# Localizable.strings keys and good practices

Tags: ios, localization

For the first time I have to localize an app, and I studied a little the docs, red some tutorials and, of course, met `Localizable.strings`.

Now, look at this image (this is from one of the [tutorials](https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881)):

[image]

The author puts a string on the left and a translation on the right side, and that's ok. Then, he "feeds" `NSLocalizedString`, passing an "understandable" key (a word or an entire sentence).

Is it considered a bad practice to have a different kind of key, eg. "t1", "t2", "t3", etc, instead of inserting real content as a key? If I have a very large text, this would help me not to have my code full of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a different kind of key is not at all a bad practice. But having a key name similar to the text is a good practice. For eg. If you want to localize this string: "Thank you for using the app. You are a great person." An appropriate key could be "Thanks_text" or "Thanks_message" or "Thanks_label" etc. Its not required to write the full string as a key.

Comment: I initially thought a similar thing, eg. "login_screen_enter_btn"

Comment: Yes, that absolutely fine.